# Dynamic runtime method in Python

Tags: python, django, dynamic-method

```
class Screening(models.Model):
  def get_omitted_1(self):
       return OmittedInformationReason.objects.get(pk=self.omitted_1).name 
  get_omitted_1 = property(get_omitted_1)
```

I want to have access to screening_instance.get_omitted_1 ,screening_instance.get_omitted_2 upto screening_instance.get_omitted_10. Is there better way to do this without creating get_omitted_1, get_omitted_2.. methods for each case like get_omitted_%d ??

I tried creating dynamic function at runtime but had some problem with it. I tried something like this:

```
def omitted_list(self,x):
    def omitted_function(self): 
        opk = "omitted_%d" % x
        return OmittedInformationReason.objects.get(pk=self.opk).name

    omitted_name = 'get_omitted_'+ str(x)

    setattr(self.__class__, omitted_name , omitted_function)
    omitted_name = property(omitted_name)

    for x in range(1, 3): 
      omitted_list(x)
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you believed that code would work...

Comment: Or why you think it would be a good idea in the first place.

Comment: I get AttributeError: 'Screening' object has no attribute 'get_omitted_1' with this code

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any possible need for this. If you need dynamic access to items, use a method: that's what they're for.

```
def get_omitted(self, number):
    return OmittedInformationReason.objects.get(pk=number)
```

Comment: By creating method like this, I wont be able to use it in django view for screening.get_omitted.1 So, dynamic method enables me to use in view as screening.get_omitted_1

Answer (score 0):

> By creating method like this, I wont be able to use it in django view
>   for screening.get_omitted.1 So, dynamic method enables me to use in
>   view as screening.get_omitted_1

Ah ha! You should have mentioned this in your original question. If you had others would have directed you to the [documentation for creating custom tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) which is the right way to solve your problem.

Once you have created your tag, in your template you can do `{% get_omitted 1 %}` and then `{% get_omitted 2 %}` and so on.